# Openjfx - IntelliJ - Maven: InvocationTargetException when creating an Item

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, openjfx

I tried to setup Openjfx with IntelliJ, but went into a compiler error though following this post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000909940-Openjfx-11

If I do not add Labels, Buttons etc., the program behaves as normal (so creating a scene and parents is ok). But everytimes I do, I get this Exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x7ecf959f) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x7ecf959f
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

This is my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        HBox box = new HBox();
        Label label = new Label("Test");        // this line throws the InvocationTargetException
        box.getChildren().add(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MoodleApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Do you have any idea what causes the Exception?

Comment: Are you sure the pom you have posted relates to the sample app? `sample.Main` doesn't match `mainClass`.

Comment: What JDK version are you using if you are using JavaFX11?

Comment: @JoséPereda Oh, thank you. But that does not solve the problem :/

Comment: @MS90 I am using jdk 11.0.2 and jre 10.0.2

Comment: Update the question with matching app and pom. Make sure you use JDK 11 with JavaFX 11.

Comment: I am using jdk 11.0.2 as well as openjfx 11.0.2 already

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try adding following in IntelliJ's `Run Configuration` inside an application's window's `VM-option`

> --module-path=D:\PATH TO YOUR LIB DIRECTORY\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib
>   --add-modules=javafx.base, javafx.controls, javafx.fxml, javafx.graphics, javafx.media, javafx.swing, javafx.web
>   --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED
>   --add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED
>   --add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAME
>   --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED

and see what happens.

Comment: Thannk you for your answer.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I only get this new Error: 

Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib

Comment: Add all missing modules to it or if you prefer take a look at this video and follow it in order to start javafx11 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn2tbftFjno